# How to return a specific SOAP response from a WCF service?

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF method which currently returns a string like so:

```
string CreateDesign(string UID, string TemplateName)
```

The retruned string is created by this method:

```
string RequestProcessed(string status, string UID)
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("RequestProcessed",
                new XElement("Status", status),
                new XElement("UID", UID)));

        return doc.ToString();
    }
```

The response that I got from using SOAPUI is like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
  <CreateDesignResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <CreateDesignResult><![CDATA[<RequestProcessed>
       <Status>OK</Status>
       <UID>FolderName</UID>
     </RequestProcessed>]]></CreateStandardResult>
  </CreateStandardResponse>
 </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

The client is expecting it like this:

```
<soap:Body>
 <m:RequestProcessed xmlns:m=" ">
  <m:Status></m:Status>
  <m:UID></m:UID>
 </m: RequestProcessed >
</soap:Body>
```

What should I do to make the WCF service return the response like that?
I am struggling with this for quite sometime now, appreciate any help.

Regards.

Comment: Have a look at the example I added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have full controll over your SOAP message body you should use MessageContract attribute for both your input and output parameters. Here is a good article on the web to start with.
[Using Message Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx)
Hope it helps!

**EDITED:**
Operation contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    RequestProcessed TestMethod(RequestInput tt);
}
```

RequestProcessed

```
[MessageContract]
public class RequestProcessed
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Guid UID { get; set; }
}
```

SOAP message body

```
<s:Body>
   <RequestProcessed xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <Status>OK</Status>
     <UID>ffd338ed-bca3-46c1-9ee3-3c92ba3b3acc</UID>
   </RequestProcessed>
</s:Body>
```